# SublimeText2: Disable cursor keys in Vintage mode

Tags: sublimetext

I am wanting to force myself to use hjkl to navigate while practising VIM in Sublime text. I.e. I would like to map the cursor keys to do nothing in insert mode.

Answer (score 3):

Add the following lines in your "Packages/User/Default.sublime-keymap".

```
[
    {"keys": ["up"], "command": "pass",
        "context": [{ "key": "setting.command_mode", "operand": false }]},
    {"keys": ["down"], "command": "pass",
        "context": [{ "key": "setting.command_mode", "operand": false }]},
    {"keys": ["left"], "command": "pass",
        "context": [{ "key": "setting.command_mode", "operand": false }]},
    {"keys": ["right"], "command": "pass",
        "context": [{ "key": "setting.command_mode", "operand": false }]}
]
```

(If you already have the file, insert {"keys" ... }]} lines before the last ] in your file.)